# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 Error when querying Excel

Tags: sql-server-2012, linked-server

I am running the following query:

```
SELECT         *
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',    
                           'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\GSS.xlsx;HDR=YES', 
                           'SELECT * FROM [DATA$]');
```

and I get the following error:

```
OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Unspecified error".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".
```

I have reproduced this error on another server and have installed the 2010 redistributable:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13255

and also the 2007 driver components:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734

Do I actually have to install a full copy of office to get this to work?

Comment: I used the 64bit one

Comment: For info I tried installing the 32bit one but I got an error that the provider couldn't be loaded into 64bit SQL

Comment: For info installing Office had no affect.